# What can I do to help someone else easily edit the website I am working on?

Tags: html, web, content-management-system

I am currently in an internship and making a website for someone. I have nearly finished the website and they would like a way to easily edit the website without messing around too much with code. They have no development team and once my internship is over, obviously they'll be stuck and they would like a way to edit the content on the website. How can I go about doing this? I mentioned a WordPress site to them but they didn't like the sound of that. Are there any other ways in which I can allow them to have this functionality?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a Wordpress-similar, with a login, and while navigating through pages they would have options normal users do not have (e.g: delete, etc).

Or you could create an admin dashboard, where there would be every settings.

I think the second one is the best option for you, as it doesn't require you to modify any pages already created, and you will not have to adapt the style of your website to those supplementary options which would be shown on every pages if you used the first option.

## Edit:

Or you could have all the content of the website in files, so that they simply need to edit the files to change the content. Even though I think option 2 is better, this one is a lot simpler to put in place.

Comment: @Ilkzz Edited to add another option.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. My programming knowledge isnt that great to create an admin dashboard. I was thinking of keeping the website hosted on their chosen host and linking some other web based application to it. Is this possible?

Could you elaborate on the third option? What do you mean by having the content of the website in files? How do I do this?

Comment: I don't understand how this could solve your problem. What other web based apps do you want to link ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont think I was clear enough. Instead of creating an admin panel, are there any pre built content management systems I can use and someone link the pages I create to that system?

Comment: It might exist, but it would probably not support your website, as everyone has a different way of coding. You could also take my 3rd proposition and add, somewhere on the website, a file editor which would edit the files which the website is based on.

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestions. I shall do some research into these areas!